# Upload de videos DataType Asp.Net MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio

Estou querendo colocar um campo de Upload de Vídeo em meu sistema Asp.Net MVC e não encontrei nada referente a videos no DataType.

Encontrei DataType variadas tais como

```
[DataType(DataType.ImageUrl)]

[DataType(DataType.Upload)]

[DataType(DataType.Url)]
```

Entre outras, qual DataType devo utilizar para realizar uploads de videos.

Answer (score 1):

Em `System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.DataType`, não existe um tipo específico no enumerador para "Video".

Se o Upload não atende as suas necessidades, você vai precisar criar a sua própria customização e isso vai dar bastante trabalho se quiser contemplar: A aparência, modos de exibição, validadores, scaffolding e helpers.

Mas, se quiser aventurar-se na tarefa de implementar o seu `Custom`, 
[consulte a documentação disponível.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/cc488557(v=vs.100).aspx)

**Obs:** Atualmente os `DataType` disponíveis são:

> **CreditCard**
>   Representa um número de cartão de crédito.
>
> **Currency**
>   Representa um valor de moeda.
>
> **Custom**
>   Representa um tipo de dados personalizado.
>
> **Date**
>   Representa um valor de data.
>
> **DateTime**
>   Representa um momento no tempo, expresso como uma data e hora do dia.
>
> **Duration**
>   Representa um tempo contínuo durante o qual um objeto existe.
>
> **EmailAddress**
>   Representa um endereço de email.
>
> **Html**
>   Representa um arquivo HTML.
>
> **ImageUrl**
>   Representa uma URL para uma imagem.
>
> **MultilineText** 
>   Representa texto de várias linhas.
>
> **Password**
>   Representa um valor de senha.
>
> **PhoneNumber**
>   Representa um valor de número de telefone.
>
> **PostalCode**
>   Representa um código postal.
>
> **Text**
>   Representa o texto que é exibido.
>
> **Time**
>   Representa um valor temporal.
>
> **Upload**
>   Representa o tipo de dados de upload de arquivo.
>
> **Url**
>   Representa um valor de URL.

[Fonte](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.datatype(v=vs.110).aspx)